# def self.methodName vs def methodName

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails Models, I've seen what I'm assuming are called class methods defined either by

```
def methodName
   #do something
end
```

and

```
def self.methodName
   #do something
end
```

I can't seem to find anywhere that gives a description of the differences between these two, and when you should use one vs the other.

Also not sure if this is specific to Ruby, Rails or other languages as well. 
Thanks

Comment: What is your question?(TM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `User` model

1. Instance methods

   ```
    def methodName

       #do something
    end
   ```

to call this method use

```
User.new.methodName
```

1. Class Methods

   ```
   def self.methodName #OR User.methodName
     #do something
   end
   ```

to call this method use

```
User.methodName
```

Answer (score 3):

The first one is an instance method, the second one is a class method. You can find more info [here](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)

Answer (score 1):

Not both are class methods.

`def methodName` is an instance method, while def `self.methodName` is a class method.

The difference between both can be explained like in the example below.

```
class MyClass
  def instance_method_name
  end

  def self.class_method_name
  end
end


MyClass.class_method_name
MyClass.new.instance_method_name
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "class method" in Ruby. Your `class_method` is an instance method just like any other instance method, in particular, it's an instance method of `MyClass`'s singleton class.

Comment: The rubydoc disagrees with you. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html